# MS Access 2013 Web App - Create unique value for field between 0 and 9999

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

I have a table where I need the field "DirNum" to be a unique number between 0 and 9999. In addition, the user needs to be able to manually assign a "random" unique number to this field as long as it is between 0 and 9999 (such as the number 8000).

Since its not feasible to expect my user to guess unique numbers every time, I would like to have the ability to create this number for them. I'm pretty open as to how I should do this.

So what I have considered:

- Make the default value this unique number
- Make a control button
  that inserts this unique number
- Make the "New" control button
  insert this new record

Problem is, I don't really know how to go about doing this.

I would assume the best way to do this would be to query all the existing values for "DirNum" and assign the lowest value to the new record. But I don't even know where to start when coding this.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function in vba to do this.  This will return the next available id or 0 if none are available.  The 9999 sets the upper limit.

```
Public Function getNextAvailableID() As Integer

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select ID From TestUniqueNumber order by id", dbOpenSnapshot)
Dim intLastID As Integer
Dim intNextAvailableID As Integer

intLastID = 0
With rst
    .MoveFirst

    Do Until .EOF Or intLastID = 9999
        If rst!ID - intLastID > 1 Then
            intNextAvailableID = intLastID + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        intLastID = rst!ID


        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
getNextAvailableID = intNextAvailableID
End Function
```

If you had many more rows than 9999 and vba was too slow, you could look into an SQL statement to handle this.